# JW Player Shows Blank Video In Explorer After Hiding and Showing

Tags: flash, video, jwplayer, explorer

In Internet Explorer 7 and 8 (WinXP/Flash 10), if I play my videos using the JW Player in the slider they work. However if I move to the next slide and then return to the original slide the video is no longer displayed - the audio is still audible and the video can be played and paused, but there is no image.

I've asked this question on longtailvideo.com, but the support member cannot see this problem on their computer. Does anyone else see this issue, and if so, any help to fix it would be appreciated.

You can view the slider and video here: http://ghostpool.com/wordpress/phideo/

Comment: i didn't see the video on that page at all, using Chrome 6.x and firefox 3.6.x. Looks like IE didn't fire some event to stop video handler.

Comment: @Eugene: I was editing the site, so the video was removed. It's back up now. Do you have any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This solved a similar problem for me...

http://blog.evansamek.com/2011/06/22/jwplayer-internet-explorer-jquery-bug-fix/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.